# pass parameters and execute another PHP script

Tags: php, text

I have a php script script1.php. I want to pass arguments to script2.php and execute it from script1.php. (script2.php saves the output to a text file which is used in script1.php)

Edit:

This is my script2.php

```
require_once('showtimes/simple_html_dom/simple_html_dom.php');

$html = new simple_html_dom();
//$requested4=$_GET['place'];
$html->load_file('http://www.google.com/movies?near=${requested4}&hl=en');
ob_start(); 

$muv='<pre>';
foreach($html->find('#movie_results .theater') as $div) {
    // print theater and address info
$muv=$muv."Theatre:  ".$div->find('h2 a',0)->innertext."\n";
$muv=$muv."Address: ". $div->find('.info',0)->innertext."\n";

    // print all the movies with showtimes
    foreach($div->find('.movie') as $movie) {
       $muv=$muv."\tMovie:    ".$movie->find('.name a',0)->innertext.'<br />';
      $muv=$muv."\tTime:    ".$movie->find('.times',0)->innertext.'<br />';
    }
    $muv=$muv. "\n\n";
}
$muv=$muv."</pre>";
//ob_get_contents(); 
ob_end_clean(); 
echo $muv;
file_put_contents('textfiles/file.txt', $muv);  
$html->clear();

?>
```

If I just execute this it works normally, but if I include it in script1.php i get this error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /home/anandheg/public_html/anandghegde.in/se/showtimes/simple_html_dom/simple_html_dom.php on line 879
```

also, I don't have permissions on the server for shell executions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply include the script2.php inside the script1.php

```
include 'script2.php';
```

You don't have to pass the parameter in the `script2.php`, variables which exists before the `include` statement will be available in script2.php as normal.

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks in order to call system command

```
<?php
`script1.php any_command_line_options_goes_here`;

//example
`/usr/bin/php -i`;
```

Then you can read file after execution in you script1.php

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the the question.

Comment: Found the answer I was looking for


`$data = file_get_contents('http://domain.com/a.php?this=that&that=this');`